# SPgridView filtering Menu issues for Numeric column

Tags: sharepoint-designer, asp.net, spgridview

I have built a SPgridview with Filtering, Sorting and Paging.
In the grid , i have one numeric type column and other are string columns.

There is a issue while filtering the numeric type column, the filter column showing the values in ascending order like (10000, 10001, 12,145,..... ).

Actually it sorting the values in string type instead of nueric type..

Expected result should be like that 12,145, 10000, 10001,.......

i have spent much time in google.. Not able to find the solution. Pls help.

How to fix the issue?
Thanks